# Why is the Kanji 「驍」read 「たける」?

Tags: kanji, manga

I have found a manga name called 覇王伝説 **驍**. Then, I have looked up several Kanji dictionary and they do not give such the pronunciation, the almost close one is 「たけし」.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is simply because when it comes to people names there are sometimes just a lot more readings than usual. Have you tried to look as well on some 人名漢字辞典?

If you look 驍 up [here](http://kanji.reader.bz/) for example, "Takeru" is listed as a possible reading. There is a discussion about the readings of such kanji [here](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1128291216) as well. Hope it helps, as simple as the answer is.